# Flutter: Wrap & Column for displaying multiple icons vertically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a vertical list of icons. I decided to use Wrap & Column widgets for that. However, the spacing between the icons is too big. I did use spacing, but it doesn't seem to help. Any thoughts on how I can make spacing smaller?

```
child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(child: Text('Title')),
                            Container(child: Text('Category')),
                          ],
                          ),
                    ),
                    Wrap(
                      direction: Axis.vertical,
                      spacing: 1,
                      runSpacing: 1,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                          iconSize: 14,
                          onPressed: null,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.star_outline),
                          iconSize: 14,
                          onPressed: null,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                          iconSize: 14,
                          onPressed: () => deleteTx(tx.id),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw8p3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can

Just put 'em in containers and set to each height, for example - 20

Here your container with mods

```
Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          spacing: 1,
          runSpacing: 1,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 20,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 20,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_outline),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 20,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: but i advice to you read more about adaptive widgets such Flex, Flexible and others

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a height for icons to space evenly in only that height. Try this.

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    height: 200,
    child: Card(
      child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(width: 10,color: Colors.purple),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(child: Text('Title')),
                Container(child: Text('Category')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Wrap(
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            spacing: 1,
            runSpacing: 1,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_outline),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                iconSize: 14,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
),
    ),
  )
```